# SQL Convert float to comma varchar with decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point

I have a couple floats that are kinda big. They're around a 100 million.

I would like this number to show like the following 123,456,789.01234

I've found that I can use CONVERT if its a money datatype but this doesn't do the full trick (it leaves off some decimal places).

I have to have commas on the left and five decimal places on the right.

Is there any built in SQL function to help with this? Or do I have to write a custom function?

Thanks

*** Update

- I forgot to mention that I'm just displaying these as varchars. So there isn't any calculations after this.
- This is running on an SQL database so MySQL and Oracle won't work.

Comment: can you just find the SQL server equivalent and use that?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @f FLOAT

SET @f = 123456789.01234

SELECT  LEFT('$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(@f AS MONEY), 1), LEN(@f) - 2)
```

this will cut it up to two places of decimal for formatting. You can change LEN(@f) - 2 to modify this setting.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just displaying this as text you can do the following:

oracle :

```
select to_char(123456789.01234,'999,999,999.99999') from dual; => 123,456,789.01234
```

MySQL :

```
select format(123456789.01234,5) => 123,456,789.01234<br>
```

the MySQL function rounds

Comment: The rounding is no problem. You must always round a float for display anyway, as it cannot store many decimal fractions exactly.